# SOAP WSDL Parsing Error

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am having some trouble setting up a SoapClient with PHP.  It seems the problem I am having is a relatively common one, but I have yet to find a suitable solution.  I am using the following code to connect:

```
    $varIDs = array();
    $varIDs[0] = '2147483732';


    try{
        $client = new SoapClient("../../../../ASP/webservice1.asmx?WSDL");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e . '<br>';
    }
```

I am getting the standard errors, listed below, about not being able to load the WSDL file.

```
[07-Aug-2012 12:11:17] PHP Warning:  SoapClient::SoapClient() [<a href='soapclient.soapclient'>soapclient.soapclient</a>]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;../../../../ASP/webservice1.asmx?WSDL&quot; in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\php\utils\getISOxml.php on line 7
[07-Aug-2012 12:11:17] PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from '../../../../ASP/webservice1.asmx?WSDL' in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\php\utils\getISOxml.php on line 7
```

I'm not sure what the issue is here.  When I go to the URL in a browser, I get valid XML (never worked with WSDL before, so I'm just assuming that it's valid).  Any suggestions?

EDIT: As per the suggestion below from @Madbreaks, I tried changing the URL I was pointing to (it now reads 'http://vm0281sch/ATS/webservice2.asmx?WSDL').  At first I thought it was working, because it was taking forever to respond, but I'm not sure about that- it gives me a new error, but I'm still not getting anything.  I now get the error shown below:

```
[07-Aug-2012 16:16:42] PHP Warning:  SoapClient::SoapClient(http://vm0281sch/ASP/webservice1.asmx?WSDL) [<a href='soapclient.soapclient'>soapclient.soapclient</a>]: failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\php\utils\getISOxml.php on line 6
```

This is followed by the errors I was getting before.  I'm not sure what happened here, but it seems that the issue is in fact related somehow to the URL I am using.

Comment: When you go to *what* URL in a browser?

Comment: I just came across [this](http://www.digipedia.pl/usenet/thread/15676/652/), which claims that I cannot call a web service that is on my current server, but I'm not sure that I put any stock in that.

Comment: I think the above article may have been correct- I tried making the request from another page, and though I don't receive the expected reply from the server, I am no longer getting an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your URI is invalid, the errors are pretty clear - the resource isn't found.  You're specifying a file path, but your question says you get valid XML when you visit "the URL".  Put the same URL in your code, instead of a relative file path.

*EDIT*

If what you say is true, try this:

```
$client = new SoapClient(dirname(__FILE__)."/../../../../ASP/webservice1.asmx?WSDL");
```

While you're at it, put this right before that line:

```
error_log('In dir: '.dirname(__FILE__));
```

*EDIT*

Based on what you've stated below, try loading the WSDL like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost/ASP/webservice1.asmx?WSDL');
```

Comment: when I say I've been to the URL, I mean that I've gone to the URL with that PHP code in it, then added the relative path.  The relative path is correct as it is printed.

Comment: Why are you hitting the webservice using relative path? Why dont you directly hit it using the fully qualified url?

Comment: @Raidenace Why are you asking op a question in my answer?  Ask in the comments section of the question.  But for what it's worth, a URL isn't required: http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

Comment: This may be an issue- that is not where the file is in the file system, but rather where it is in the server.  The directory ASP is not in the 'htdocs' directory of my server, but it is mounted to show up at 'localhost/ASP/'.  Is there no way to make the constructor view the path as a URL rather than a directory?

Comment: Results on this attempt were too long- made it an edit to the original post.

Comment: Did you try `localhost` as I suggested?

Comment: I tried localhost, but that didn't change anything.  I think the problem may be the issue I cited above- trying to access a web service on the local server as opposed to using it from a different server.  When I run the same code from a non-local server, I get a response from the service.